# Jenkins: What I can't do in declarative pipeline which is possible in scripted pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I am newbie to Jenkins pipeline. I got to know there is 2 types of Jenkins pipeline-
1. scripted pipeline
2. declarative pipeline

while reading, I got one major key difference between "scripted pipeline" and "declarative pipeline" -
1. Scripted pipeline provides very few limits, pipeline structure and syntax tend to be defined by Groovy itself, rather than any Pipeline-specific systems, making it an ideal choice for "power-users" and those with more complex requirements.
2. Declarative pipeline strictly limits what is available to the user with pre-defined structure, making it an ideal choice for "simpler users" with simple continuous delivery pipelines.

Please share an example where "Scripted Pipeline" wins over "Declarative Pipeline" and how user becomes a "power-user" by putting thier extra effort?

Comment: apparently nothing